# How to update GCP Functions source from gitlab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an existing GCP Function just with the default hello-world source. I would like to push updates to the Function's source from Gitlab. I have setup the gitlab-ci.yml file and necessary service accounts but I keep getting an error that the function already exists and to delete the conflicting function first or use a different function name. I am not trying to create a new function, only update the source code of an existing one.

Thank you

Here's the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
- deploy

deploy-cloud-function:
  stage: deploy
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  script:
    - echo $GCP_ACCOUNT_KEY > gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud config set project myprojectname
    - gcloud functions deploy myfunctionname
      --source=.
      --trigger-http
      --runtime=python310

  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
```

Here's the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[Failed to create function, function myfunctionname already exists under 2nd gen environment. Please delete conflicting function first or deploy the function with a different name.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73618600/cant-deploy-or-delete-a-google-cloud-function

Comment: My existing function is already a gen2. I'm not trying to delete and recreate. I just want the source code updated in the existing gen2 function.

Comment: It's the same error message.  Maybe it's a related problem.  That's why I reference here - in case there is something that helps someone now or in the future.